# Don't reset search bar in top bar after searching on stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, search, top-bar, stackexchange.com

When [searching on a Stack Exchange site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=test), your query is shown both in the top bar and just above the search results:

[image: search results on Meta Stack Exchange]

However, this is not the case when doing a [networkwide search on stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=test). There, the search bar in the top bar gets reset, only the other one is showing the query:

[image: search results on stackexchange.com]

I prefer the search bar not getting reset, since that's where I entered my original query.

Comment: Rather than "frame challenge" I'll comment: Not only is [main site](https://stackexchange.com/) different from the other sites, but https://stackoverflow.com/ is different too. Using your example: [Search "test"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=test&mixed=0) it **drops the** ***2nd*** **search bar**, and the reason is probably due to **Teams**; because if you repeat that search (without blocking 'Team results', ***if*** you *are* on at least one Team), like this: [Search "test"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=test) the **2nd** bar is dumped, because having multiple ones would be weird.